# Not unique table/alias: 'categories'.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this mysql code that retrieves the most popular descriptions in each category by how many times they appear in the database -

It grab's the list however it echo's out the data like this

```
"Adidas was the most popular in category 5 with 1 occurrences"
```

My table structure for this interests (hobbies) is

```
 # interests
 CREATE TABLE `interests` (
 `interestID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `categoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `interest_desc` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`interestID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8   


# categories
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `categoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is my SQL command:

```
SELECT 
   interest_desc, 
   categoryID, 
   MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat,
   category_name
FROM
(
   SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
   FROM interests
   GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
) subsel
JOIN categories ON subsel.categoryID = categories.ID 
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID, category_name
```

I'm receiving this error:

> Not unique table/alias: 'categories'

Comment: 1. You should show your table structure ; 2. This question should be focused only on your SQL query, instead of PHP (as the PHP part has no problem)

Comment: I know my table structure, i have 2 tables one with the secondary key as categoryID, the other with it as a primary. How would i edit the sql query to involve the second table, as my sql query is only focused on the first table that only has the categoryID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inner join against your `categories` table (you supply the correct table and column names) is all you need to complete this:

```
SELECT 
  interest_desc, 
  categoryID, 
  MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat,
  category_name
FROM
(
   SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
   FROM interests
   GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
) subsel
JOIN categories ON subsel.categoryID = categories.ID 
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID, category_name
```

Comment: Just trying to make your answer work, i get this mysql error - Not unique table/alias: 'categories'.  I have linked the tables through designer in sql. What would be the issue?

Comment: @DIM3NSION What is the actual name of your table? If it isn't `categories`, supply the correct name above.  Also, I just found there as an errant comma in the `ON` clause -- `subsel,categoryID` should be `subsel.categoryID`.

Comment: My table is called categories though :S i have edited with your update.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. More optimal if it works, joining

   `SELECT s.interest_desc, c.name, MAX(s.num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
   FROM
   (
      SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
      FROM interests
      GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
   ) s
       INNER JOIN categories c ON c.ID = s.categoryID
   GROUP BY s.interest_desc, s.categoryID`

   OR
2. Less optimal adding another select as a column

   `SELECT s.interest_desc, (SELECT name from categories c WHERE c.ID = s.categoryID), MAX(s.num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
   FROM
   (
      SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
      FROM interests
      GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
   ) s
   GROUP BY s.interest_desc, s.categoryID`